# Identical transformation about integrals

Tags: partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

\begin{align}
I &=\int_0^1dr\int_0^{2\pi}\left(cos\theta\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+sin\theta\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)rd\theta=\int_0^1dr\int_{\color{red}{x^2+y^2=r^2}}\left({\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}dy-{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}dx\right) \\
& \quad =\color{blue}{\int_0^1dr\iint_{x^2+y^2\le r^2}\left(\frac{{\partial}^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{{\partial}^2 f}{\partial y^2}\right)dxdy}=\color{green}{\int_0^1dr\iint_{x^2+y^2\le r^2}\left(x^2y^2\right)dxdy} \\
& \quad \quad =\int_0^1dr\int_0^r{\rho}^5d\rho\int_0^{2\pi}cos^2\theta sin^2\theta d\theta
\end{align}

Green part is given by another equation, so just forget it. I don't understand why the range(red part) become a equation like this; and for the blue part, I have totally no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original integral is a double integral on the unit disk. The second equality (the one with the red part) comes from changing the polar coordinate double integral to line integral on the circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ where $r$ varies from $0$ to $1$. This covers the whole double integral on the disk. The next equality comes from Green's Theorem, which says that
$$\int_C Pdx+Qdy=\iint_D \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dxdy$$

if $C$ is a positively oriented, piecewise smooth, simple, closed curve and $D$ is the region enclosed by $C$.

Comment: I haven't studied line integral and Green's Theorem yet. Maybe I should look for another way to solve my origin question. Thanks anyway. I have been working for this all night :-(

Comment: That's too bad. I would think there is no way to bypass that. Since the integral with the red part is apparently a line integral, by definition. And unless you derive Green's theorem by yourself, you will have to use it to get the next one. Maybe see here for a reference: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LineIntegralsPtI.aspx.